# Prove that $g(x)=0$ for all $x$ in $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

> Suppose that the function $g:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is continuous and that $g(x)=0$ if $x$ is rational. Prove that $g(x)=0$ for all $x$ in $\mathbb{R}$.

---

Proof:

Let $\{x_n\}$ be a sequence of $\mathbb{Q}$, then the limit of $\{x_n\}$ is in $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}f(x_n)=f(x)=0$ where $x\in\mathbb{Q}$. And by that fact that $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense of $\mathbb{R}$, so the limit of $\{x_n\}$ is in $\mathbb{R}$. Thus, since the function $g:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is continuous, we can conclude that $g(x)=0,\forall x\in\mathbb{R}$.

---

It seems I just put everything into my proof to convince me that is right. Can anyone check my solution? Thanks

Comment: Why is the limit of $(x_n)$ in $\mathbb Q$?

Comment: @Bungo That should be $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: I think your idea is right, but it's not stated quite right. Start with an arbitrary $x \in \mathbb R$. We want to show that $g(x) = 0$. Since $\mathbb Q$ is dense in $\mathbb R$, there is a sequence $(x_n)$ with $x_n \in \mathbb Q$ such that $x_n \to x$...

Comment: You can't conclude the first {$x_n$} converges at all nor that it converges to a point in Q.  Q doesn't have the least upper bound property so *many* sequences in Q converge to a point in R (not Q).  *MANY* sequences do that.  And it doesn't matter what {$x_n} does when you try to evaluate f for a completely different y.  *Start* with x in R.  From this x in R claim there is a sequence {x_n} in Q that converges to x in R.  THAT IS ALLOWABLE as that is the definition of R.  Then as f is continuous f(x) = lim f(x_n) and as all f(x_n) = 0, lim f(x_n) = 0.

Comment: Ah that comment of R rather than Q makes your explanation *much* clearee and much closer to being correct.  My only correction would be to start with the specific x and get the sequence to it, rather than the other way around.

Comment: @fleablood, is it possible to let $x$ be a irrational number?

Comment: Yes.  In fact you  *have* to have x be an irrational number, else you haven't figured out f(x) for x not in Q.  R has the least upper bound property.  So the DEFINITION of real numbers is that i) every bounded sequence of rational number converges to a *real* number (even if the sequence does not converge to a *rational* number) and ii) every real number (rational or otherwise) has a sequence of *rational* numbers that converge to it.  It's really subtle and to be honest it went over my head when I was a student.  But that is what real numbers actually are.  This can be a very powerful tool.

Comment: See, it's not just that the rationals have "holes" at spots like sqrt2 or pi. And it's not that we measure the reals with some "hyper-yard sticks" that measure things that "rational yard sticks" can't. It's that the rationals get infinitely close to every real so there are *rational* numbers that converge to sqrt2 and pi.  And we *don't* have any yard stick to measure the irrational numbers; we measure by knowing their *definition* is the *limit* of the rational sequence and that that *limit* is very much a "real" number; every bit as much a real number as though we *did* have a yardstick.

Comment: @fleablood thanks for the detail explanation

Comment: @fleablood: Just to be pedantic, it is not true that every bounded sequence of rational numbers converges to a real number. (Consider $x_n = (-1)^n$ for example.) But it is true that every bounded sequence of rational numbers (or of real numbers) has a subsequene which converges. Also, any *monotone* bounded sequence converges.

Comment: @Bungo.  You are of course correct.  I should be more careful in my usage.  It's a "forest for the trees" thing.  Every one has an intuitive idea of what sequence that "gets closer and closer together" means.  I was trying to impress this idea but without any of the sloppy traps it can lay.  In hindsight, the thing that eluded me as a student was, when we "filled in the holes" with sqrt(2) and pi etc.  I thought of it as filling in *specific* holes.  I missed the *big* idea that we were filling in *all* holes by saying all these type of sequences all go somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As fleablood pointed out, your argument as it is now is flawed.

I would like to suggest a point-set-topology way to prove the extension proposition, which may be cleaner in nature: we prove (1) if $f,g: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ are continuous, then the set $S$ of all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x)=g(x)$ is closed in $\mathbb{R}$; (2) with $f := 0$ and $f = g$ on $\mathbb{Q}$, the set $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$ and $S \supset \mathbb{Q}$ only if $f=g$ on $\mathbb{R}$.

To prove (1), it suffices to prove that $\mathbb{R}\setminus S$ is open in $\mathbb{R}$. Let $a \in \mathbb{R} \setminus S$; then $f(a) \neq g(a)$ by assumption; let $d := |f(a) - g(a)|$. By continuity assumption, there is some open ball $V^{a}$ of center $a$ such that $x \in V^{a}$ only if 
$
|f(x) - f(a)|, |g(x)-g(a)| < d/2;
$
if there is some $x \in V^{a}$ such that $f(x) = g(x)$, then by triangle inequality we have 
$$
|f(a) - g(a)| \leq |f(x)-f(a)| + |f(x) - g(x)| + |g(x) - g(a)| < d,
$$ 
a contradiction; hence $x \in V^{a}$ only if $f(x) \neq g(x)$, and we have proved (1). Now (2) follows immediately as indicated above.

Comment: What does open ball mean?

Comment: May I know if you have any metric-space background? If not, I will delete my answer. :)

Comment: @ Gudson Chou Yes, I did.

Comment: Oh, let $(X,d)$ be a metric space; let $x \in X$; let $\varepsilon > 0$; then an open ball of center $x$ and radius $\varepsilon$ is the set of all $\xi \in X$ such that $d(\xi, x) < \varepsilon$.